# Parallel routines working at the same time

Tags: python

I would like to do something in Python that I don't even know if it'll be possible or not.

I have a routine called "A" which is creating objects and doing some calculations. I need to extract the object's properties from "A" (which are stocked into a list) and put it into an Excel doing some other tasks (we're going to call "B" the routine that will extract the info from "A" and that will create the Excel).

Can I run "A" and "B" separately to improve the performance ? (B should be scanning "A" and when a result is ready put it into the Excel and wait for another result)

Comment: Two threads and a queue.

Comment: Yes, you can use threads and a queue. Thread A does the A work and puts results on the queue. Thread B gets the results and does B work.